# Loop through data in form based on date APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to make some kind of wizard (APEX FORM) to help update data from table - i would like to loop specified data based on date (fe. looping through items updated >30 days ago) in APEX form and update them by using the apex form.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | XXXXXX |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Cell 3 | XXXXXX |

So if cell contains 'XXXXXX' in popup form should be inserted data from 1 row and by clicking button 'next' data should be update and then go to row 3 etc.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. Sample table's first row contains XXXXXX in Column B. How is that represented in your Apex application? As an interactive report? Classic report? Interactive grid? Something else (if so, what)? You said that there should be a "popup form" and it should insert data from 1 (one) row. Which "one row"? What value should it insert into Column B (actually, update that table)? Then you'd skip the 2nd row (which has "Cell 4" in Column B) and go to the 3rd row. Then what?

Comment: How about creating a stored procedure which would do that job? I mean, why would you manually update rows, one-by-one? Who knows how many rows are there in the last 30 days ... Besides, how do you (or we) know *which* rows represent those "30 days"? There's no DATE datatype column in sample table you posted.